# Save Facebook Image/URL in Parse DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

```
        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];     

        NSString *urlString = [pictureURL absoluteString];
        FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
                NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
                NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];

                NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

                NSString *urlString = [pictureURL absoluteString];
                NSLog(@"sting=%@",urlString);


                PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];

                me[@"facebookId"] = userData[@"id"];
                me["pictureURL"] = userData[urlString];
                me[@"username"] = userData[@"name"];
                [me saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error to store=%@",error.localizedDescription);
                    }
                }];
                [self presentViewController:push animated:YES completion:nil];

            } else {
                    [self presentViewController:push animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
        }];
```

I need to store the Facebook Image or URL when any new user login into my app. AFAIK we can't save the url directly so tried to convert it into NSString but then it threw error "'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'"

Is there any way so that I can store that link or any other alternate way to save directly the Image into Parse?

Comment: You should update your question to show the code that is actually causing the issue.

Comment: Updated the code above. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most likely being caused by the following line:

```
me["pictureURL"] = userData[urlString];
```

You most likely want this to be:

```
me["pictureURL"] = urlString;
```

As you have it, you will setting `me[@"pictureURL"]` to `nil` because you probably don't have a value in `userData` with a key matching `urlString`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the url should be converted to data then saved as a PFFile.

```
NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?    type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

NSData *data = [NSData contentsOfURL:picureURL]; 
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:data];

//save it 
[file saveInBackground];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: A good answer explains what the OP was doing wrong and explains how the answer solves the problem. Don't just post code with no explanation and simple state "hope that helps". How does it help?